# How to use updated state right after updating state without using Class approach in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, react-state, react-forms

I have an AddProduct component which's child is Furniture component (code seen below) which has 3 children - 3 input fields. Changing input values automatically updates dimensions state in Furniture.

After submiting form on AddProduct component I want to save dimensions to database in format ..x..x.. (example: 120x100x200) using components Furniture constant dimensionsArray.

**The error is that** parent component AddProduct uses the penultimate state not the latest.

**Example of error**: If I enter height: 123, width: 123, length: 123 then component AddProduct saves dimensions as 123x123x12 missing the last entered value.

How can I fix this issue without using Class approach (meaning without componentDidMount or setState)?

Howl form including link to github can be seen here: http://tedisproject.infinityfreeapp.com/addproduct

```
import { useState, useRef, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from "react";
import FurnitureHeight from "./FurnitureHeight";
import FurnitureWidth from "./FurnitureWidth";
import FurnitureLength from "./FurnitureLength";

const Furniture = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({
    height: "",
    width: "",
    length: "",
  });

  const changeDimensions = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e;
    setDimensions((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));

    const dimensionsArray = [
      dimensions["height"],
      dimensions["width"],
      dimensions["length"],
    ];

    props.setValue({
      value: dimensionsArray.join("x"),
      name: "specificAttribute",
    });
  };

  return (
    <div id="Furniture">
      <FurnitureHeight
        changeDimensions={changeDimensions}
        changeIsValid={changeIsValid}
        ref={dimensionsRef}
      />
      <FurnitureWidth
        changeDimensions={changeDimensions}
        changeIsValid={changeIsValid}
        ref={dimensionsRef}
      />
      <FurnitureLength
        changeDimensions={changeDimensions}
        changeIsValid={changeIsValid}
        ref={dimensionsRef}
      />
    </div>
  );
});
export default Furniture;
```

Comment: You should use the `useRef` hook for the values. You dont need to trigger re-render of the ocmponent when the value changes, so there is no need to use the `useState` hook.

Comment: @Croolman could you please explain more in detail? Googling useRef didn't help me to understand how can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use the value of the state to build `dimensionsArray` and the state update asynchronously, so you always get the old value. To solve this you can set the new dimensions in a variable and use it to update the state and build your array:

```
const changeDimensions = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e;

  const newDimensions = {
    ...dimensions,
    [name]: value
  };

  setDimensions(newDimensions);

  const dimensionsArray = [
    newDimensions["height"],
    newDimensions["width"],
    newDimensions["length"],
  ];

  props.setValue({
    value: dimensionsArray.join("x"),
    name: "specificAttribute",
  });
};
```

Comment: This solution will work, effectively bypassing the update of the state, which even without knowing the rest of the app should not be need at all.

Comment: @Arkellys thank you! Croolman I will evaluate your comment tomorrow!